# Dynamic Sequelize db connection in Nestjs with the endpoint we pass a database name

Tags: dynamic, sequelize.js, nestjs

setup a dynamic sequlize db connection in nest js
when we call an endpoint it selects a db and fetches data same model in 2 databases.
there is an endpoint for fetch data we give parameters to select database.
so it chooses the database and fetches data from it in efficient way

Comment: Define model registration functions and use them to register models in both Sequelize connections.

Comment: have some solution for this